# Cant manually deploy .war in jboss(wildfly)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

So, cant deploy .war in jboss (wildfly 8 final), catch this errors

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./education" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./education: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookCommentsDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.education.Dao.BookComments.Comments.BookCommentsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookCommentsDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.education.Dao.BookComments.Comments.BookCommentsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.education.Dao.BookComments.Comments.BookCommentsDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class"}}}}
```

But on my local wildfly 8 everything works fine. With Intellij idea build this war on local machine, then upload to remote jboss and catch this. How to solve?

Comment: "nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class" Are you hot-deploying this without stopping/starting the server?

Comment: No, try hot-deploy, cause of this
If server stopped - i cant use web-interface or CLI, in this case - cant deploy

Comment: I'm guessing that the version of Java on the server is not compatible with the version of Java used to compile the class then.

Comment: Server use last java, and IDEA too, but how to check it?

Comment: You ask the person who maintains the server of course. I suggest googling the root error 'java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class' to see what possibly causes there are, I see some different ones from my guess.

Comment: Try to build with 1.7 version, before use 1.6, no result

Comment: I would rather expect the other way around (compile with older because the runtime on the server is older), but I would do the Google I suggested and find better reasons for this error to occur.

Comment: Last 2 weeks google cant help me with this issue, server use last versions for sure

Comment: UPD:
Try to deploy in glassfish on other server, this war works fine. No idea, why

Comment: I guess you're running into an early adopter problem then, Wildfly is brand-spanking new. And given RedHat's usually versioning system, 8.0-final is not really so final they'll turn it into an EAP, you're still beta testing for them.